# Is python 3.6 supported by pyinstaller or cxfreeze?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I want to create a standalone executable, I am using python 3.6 on 64 bit os. And while trying to install cx freeze I got this msg

> no matching distrubtion found for pyinstaller

Same error with cxfreeze

Answer (score 1):

3.6 is supported by both now.    `pip install pyinstaller` should work

If you are by chance using an Anaconda environment you will have to `conda install pip` before you `pip install pyinstaller`

Comment: After typing the command to install pyinstaller, this is what I got
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement. No matching distribution found for pyinstaller

Comment: That is strange, if you havent already- try download directly from pypi and manually putting it in your site-packages folder: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyInstaller/3.3.1